# sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: SQL expression, column, or mapped entity expected - got '<function news at 0x0000015CAD82CDC0>'

Tags: python, html, flask

This is the error I am facing while showing the fetched data in flask

[image: screenshot 1]

This is my python code. I am trying to retrieve news from the existing table BBC in my database in PostgreSQL. But while rendering the template I am facing this error

[image: screenshot 2]

This is the HTML code.
[image: screenshot 3]

This is my existing database
[image: screenshot 4]

Comment: Your function `def news()` is the same as your table `news = Table...`. You'll have to change the name of one of them.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it didn't work. Still showing the same error

Comment: Still says it got "function news" instead of a mapped entity? Then db.Table() is not returning the correct entity, it should return a class or SQL expression. I see your IDE highlights "Table", maybe it has a hint of why it is not working?